# Can I set a custom "system root" path with pylint?

Tags: python, embedded, pylint

I have a build system that makes a complete system image for an embedded platform.  It includes a significant amount of Python code.  Currently, I'm linting this using the target platform's Python and Pylint running under qemu but it is slow.  Really slow.

Is there a way to run the build platform's linter but using all the Python files from the target tree?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what are the "python files from the target tree" ? Are you running pylint on all your system's python file even those you did not code ?

Comment: I'm running pylint on the files that I've written, but pylint does various things with the packages that are installed on the system, too, for instance checking that all imports are present and correct.  I want these checked against the target filesystem I've built, not the packages that are installed on my build machine.

Comment: To put it another way, I'm asking the question, "If I installed pylint on the embedded target and ran it on this code, would it return any errors?"  But I want to answer that without actually installing pylint on the embedded target.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any builtin way to do that but you could:

- Use the `init_hook` option where you can modify the `sys.path` to point to your embedded target (or anything you can do in python).
- Rely on your tests (autamated or manual) for errors, and disable known false positives one by one whether by using `pylint: disable=no-member` for each or directly in the configuration with:

```
[TYPECHECK]

# List of decorators that produce context managers, such as
# contextlib.contextmanager. Add to this list to register other decorators that
# produce valid context managers.
contextmanager-decorators=contextlib.contextmanager

# List of members which are set dynamically and missed by pylint inference
# system, and so shouldn't trigger E1101 when accessed. Python regular
# expressions are accepted.
generated-members=REQUEST,
                  acl_users,
                  aq_parent

# List of class names for which member attributes should not be checked (useful
# for classes with dynamically set attributes). This supports the use of
# qualified names.
ignored-classes=SQLObject,optparse.Values,thread._local,_thread._local

# List of module names for which member attributes should not be checked
# (useful for modules/projects where namespaces are manipulated during runtime
# and thus existing member attributes cannot be deduced by static analysis). It
# supports qualified module names, as well as Unix pattern matching.
ignored-modules=

# List of decorators that change the signature of a decorated function.
signature-mutators=
```